# Code can't find resources for Serbian language

Tags: c#, .net, localization, cultureinfo

I have app writen in c#, and that app have multiple languages `en-US fr-FR`...etc.

My language files is `.resx`. So i try to add new language `Serbian` and i got exception

> {"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"Vim.lang.language.resources\" was
>   correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"AVIM\" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed."}

All other languages work good.

```
 this.culture = new CultureInfo("sr-SP-Latin", false);
 this.resourceManager = new ResourceManager(this.resourceFile, typeof(Program).Assembly);
```

How to slove this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the incorrect value, use `sr-Latn-RS`

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd997383(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Deam u save my day. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You should be using: sr-Latn-RS , source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441729.aspx ... hope this helps.. :)