# Why are certain cultures missing from CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)?

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

When I run the code below, I can create two valid cultures that are not returned in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures). Why is this the case and why are those cultures missing? I am running on Windows 10 using .NET 4.6.1

```
var allCultureNamesHashSet = new HashSet<string>(CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Select(ci => ci.Name));
var ci1 = new CultureInfo("sr-Cyrl-CS");
var ci2 = new CultureInfo("sr-Latn-CS");
var b1 = allCultureNamesHashSet.Contains(ci1.Name); //false
var b2 = allCultureNamesHashSet.Contains(ci2.Name); //false
```

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd997383(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#new-specific-cultures

Comment: This SO post may help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518647/code-cant-find-resources-for-serbian-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft:

> [New Specific Cultures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd997383(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#new-specific-cultures)

> The .NET Framework 4 also introduces new specific cultures, such as the new Serbian cultures. The old Serbian cultures were renamed to Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia and Montenegro (Former)) and Serbian (Latin, Serbia and Montenegro (Former)) to avoid display name collision. Those cultures remain in the .NET Framework with their existing information, including their culture names and culture identifiers.

[image: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd997383(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#new-specific-cultures]